# Seven dice rolls $N,X_1,...,X_6$, looking for $E(Z)$ of random variable $Z=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

After a dice is rollen seven times with the face values $N,X_1,...,X_6$, the first $N$ of the $X_i$ values are summed up. What is the expected value of $Z$?

Using the definition I have

$$\sum_z zP(Z=z)$$

And using the law of total probability, using the decomposition formed by the events $N=n$ for $n=1,...,6$

$$P(Z=z)=\sum_{n=1}^6P(Z=z|N=n)P(N=n)$$

Plugging that result back into $E(Z)$ gives

$$\sum_z z\sum_{n=1}^6P(Z=z|N=n)P(N=n)$$

---

Solution using @Henry 's hint:

Since the sums are finite:
$$\sum_z \sum_{n=1}^6zP(Z=z|N=n)P(N=n)= \sum_{n=1}^6 \sum_zzP(Z=z|N=n)P(N=n)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^6 P(N=n) \sum_zzP(Z=z|N=n)=\sum_{n=1}^6 E[zP(Z=z|N)]=E[E[Z|N]]$$

So in the end $$E[Z]=\sum_{k=1}^6 E[Z|N=k] P(N=k)$$

With $P(N=k)=1/6$, $E(Z|N=1)=3.5$, the expected value of one dice roll and the linearity of $E$ we get

$$E(Z)=3.5^2$$

Comment: I would be surprised if the answer was not $3.5^2$

Comment: @Henry How do you figure that? Gut feeling?

Comment: Yes, after I have eaten https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N_i$ be the indicator variable which takes the value $1$ if $N\ge i$ and $0$ otherwise.

$$E(Z)=E(X_1N_1+X_2N_2+X_3N_3+X_4N_4+X_5N_5+X_6N_6)$$
$$=E(X_1N_1)+E(X_2N_2)+E(X_3N_3)+E(X_4N_4)+E(X_5N_5)+E(X_6N_6)$$
$$=E(X_1)E(N_1)+E(X_2)E(N_2)+E(X_3)E(N_3)+E(X_4)E(N_4)+E(X_5)E(N_5)+E(X_6)E(N_6)$$
$$=(3.5)E(N_1)+(3.5)E(N_2)+(3.5)E(N_3)+(3.5)E(N_4)+(3.5)E(N_5)+(3.5)E(N_6)$$
$$=(3.5)(E(N_1)+E(N_2)+E(N_3)+E(N_4)+E(N_5)+E(N_6))$$
$$=(3.5)E(N_1+N_2+N_3+N_4+N_5+N_6)$$
$$=(3.5)E(N)=(3.5)(3.5)=12.25$$

Comment: I do not clearly see how $E(Z)=E(X_1N_1+X_2N_2+X_3N_3+X_4N_4+X_5N_5+X_6N_6)$. Do you care to explain? I am not used to work with indicator variables.

Comment: @B.Swan You don't see why $Z=X_1N_1+X_2N_2+X_3N_3+X_4N_4+X_5N_5+X_6N_6?$ Consider it case by case. For example, if $N=2,$ then $X_1N_1+X_2N_2+X_3N_3+X_4N_4+X_5N_5+X_6N_6=X_1\cdot1+X_2\cdot1+X_3\cdot0+X_4\cdot0+X_5\cdot0+X_6\cdot0=X_1+X_2=Z.$

Comment: Okay, I have comprehended it wrong. Somehow I thought you sum from $N$ upwards. Thanks for the clarification.